# Can't connect to my dsl connection in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

After the recent upgrade, when I tried to connect to my dsl, it shows like this..

```
Connection activation failed. (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5' failed in libnm-glib.
```

so I had to reinstall 14.10.

Some told me to reinstall the network manager when the connection is active, but how can my connection be active while I cannot connect to it ??? I could easily connect to my network in 14.10 then why is it showing such errors only in 15.04? serious problen, hope it'll be fixed soon..

Comment: Please check if you have `pppoe` installed (`sudo apt-get install pppoe`). It took me a while searching the net for an answer to this message before I saw (`tail -f /var/log/syslog`) it wasn't installed ...

Answer (score 0):

Do a:

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

then follow the instructions in the terminal. It will ask for a username and  password and other stuff.

Just answer `yes` if You don't know what to answer...

Comment: I did this but its not working, In ubuntu 14.04 I did the same then it was working good but in 15.10 not working. any other way to fix this problem.